# MySQL keeps starting logger and constantly restarts?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Alright, I have updated version 5.1 to version 5.6 without uninstalling the old one by using `update-alternatives`. This works just fine on our production/master server, but our replication slave seems to be having trouble.

First, in the processlist `mysqld_safe` just keeps starting the `logger` tool indefinitely until hundreds of instances are running and I restart the server manually.
Secondly, the server only runs for a couple seconds at a time without actually restarting. Whenever I run `status` in the MySQL shell, it has to reconnect and the status print says something like `Uptime: 9 sec`, even if it's been running for hours.

Output from `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                                   | Info                  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |    0 | Checking master version                 | NULL                  |
|  2 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |    0 | Waiting for the next event in relay log | NULL                  |
|  3 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | init                                    | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

The syslog seems fine, except that it complains about every table in the `performance_schema` database like this:

```
[ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_account_connect_attrs' has the wrong structure
```

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Update: Executing `STOP SLAVE;` stops the restarting behaviour and allows for maintenance tasks to be executed. I'm currently running `mysql_upgrade` just to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, stopping the slave replication and running the `mysql_upgrade` tool and then starting the replication again fixed the issue.